# Best practise for upgrade site collection with its separate content database in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, upgrade, content-database

In Sharepoint 2010 farm

- web application : http://www.company1.com ;content db : wss_company
- site collection  :

http://www.company1.com/products  ( /Products is a explicit managed path in company1.com webapplication)
/Products site collection has separate content db  : wss_company_products_db

**In Sharepoint 2013 farm:**

web application : http://www.company1.com 
content db : wss_company  ( it upgraded to sharepoint 2013 ,company1.com has one root site collection)
- site collection  :

http://www.company1.com/products  ( /Products is a explicit managed path in company1.com webapplication)

here i want to create /products sitecollection in  http://www.company1.com web application and with

separate content db

before doing this i want to upgrade  wss_company_products_db to sharepoint 2013

for this when i try to Mount products_db to http://www.company1.com/products it can not.

so which steps i will follow for best practise for upgrade site collection with its separate content database upgrade?

Comment: What error do you get when you try to attach the 2010 DB (wss_company_products_db) 2013? Do you already have a site collection at http://www.company1.com/products in 2013 while you try to attach the DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For upgrading site collections from 2010 to 2013, you must follow content database attach upgrade process. Below are the key steps in the process:

1. Make sure the 2013 farm has all the custom farm level solutions which are present in the 2010 farm.You must deploy the solutions to both 14 hive and 15 hive. Below is the powershell command to do that.

   Install-SPSolution -Identity solutionname.wsp -GACDeployment -CompatibilityLevel {14,15}
2. Take backup of the site collection content database from 2010 farm.
3. Restore content database into the 2013 farm.
4. Now use [Mount-SPContentDatabase](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607581.aspx)  command to attach this content database to a web application.

   Mount-SPContentDatabase -Name DatabaseName -DatabaseServer ServerName -WebApplication URL
5. Now you will be able to see the restored site collection running in 2010 UI mode.All the pages and web parts are served from 14 hive now.
6. Now you can start the visual upgrade process to make the site collection to run in 2013 mode. Go to **Site Settings**--> **Site collection Upgrade** and start the visual upgrade.
7. Once the upgrade is done , verify the [Checklists for reviewing upgraded sites](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1a2d3108-3b51-4837-a3c8-6a2cfbf961dd#Review)

Download this PDF for [SharePoint 2013 Upgrade process](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30371)

**Some key troubleshooting tips:**

1. Make sure that for each web application the root site collection is upgraded first.
2. Make sure the user account performing upgrade has **db_owner** database role
3. In Central Administration, click Upgrade and Migration, and then click Check upgrade status. Check the upgrade log file. Log file will be present in the 15 hive logs folder with name **Upgrade-YYYYMMDD-HHMMSS-SSS-error.log**

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround create a site collection in SharePoint 2013, detach the newly created content database and then attach the 2010 content database to the site collection. SharePoint 2013 will upgrade it for you. The process is explained [here](http://www.orcsweb.com/blog/cory-granata/how-to-upgrade-sharepoint-2010-to-sharepoint-2013-using-database-attach/)

Step by Step guide to Migrate from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013:
http://www.lepide.com/blog/step-by-step-guide-to-migrate-from-sharepoint-2010-to-sharepoint-2013/

Check this article to get in detailed on how plan to upgrade site collections to SharePoint 2013 and how to plan for upgrade evaluation sites, notifications, and throttling in SharePoint 2013:
*technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff191199.aspx*